# Como extraio valores de um json para inserir em uma tabela no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Preciso migrar do *sql server 2017* para o *postgreSQL*,mas nunca utilizei *postgreSQL* e estou com dificuldade.
Preciso converter um *array* *json* para valores que são inseridos na tabela.

No *sql server* eu utilizava um `insert` com `select openjson` e á clausula `with` para especificar o que eu pegaria do *json*.

```
valores json := '[
    {"tipo":"a","valor:"10.89}
    {"tipo":"b","valor:"10.88}
    {"tipo":"c","valor:"10.87}
    {"tipo":"d","valor:"10.86}
]';
insert into dbo.testedojson(valor,tipo)
select * 
from json_populate_record(NULL::dbo.testedojson,valores);
```

Peguei este exemplo na *internet* para fazer um teste,`dbo.testedojson` é a tabela que receberá os valores porém existe um erro de sintaxe que não encontro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do [Postgres 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) você pode utilizar a função **json_populate_recordset**

> Expands the outermost array of objects in from_json to a set of rows whose columns match the record type defined by base (see note below).
>
> *Expande a matriz de objetos mais externa de from_json para um conjunto de linhas cujas colunas correspondem ao tipo de registro
>   definido pela base (veja a nota abaixo).*

Exemplo retirado do [Git hub - usuário bwestergard](https://gist.github.com/bwestergard/d8d522c1f09dba03ee4a#file-json_populate_recordset-md) - segue abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT * from json_populate_recordset(null::foo,'[ 
{
   "id":0,
   "a":"harold",
   "b":"wilson",
   "c":"j"
},
{
   "id":1,
   "a":"brian",
   "b":"wilson",
   "c":"q"
},
{
   "id":2,
   "a":"jack",
   "b":"kemp",
   "c":"q"
} ]'); 
COMMIT;
```